# How to get all equivalent branches on git working copy?

Tags: bash, git

With `git branch` I can only ever get a single branch as the "current" one, even though the commit checked out matches more than one branch.

In tools like `tig` all the branches that point to the same commit. For example:

```
master upstream/master origin/master
```

How can I extract this information from `git` itself?

I would like to have this visible on my prompt (it is important for me to know that my working copy is in line with upstream/master when I am working on pushing out code). Is there any command line tool that will give me this info?

Currently my bash prompt includes

```
/usr/bin/git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
```

which will only show "(master)" (i.e. the local branch).

Comment: `git status` will tell you the status of a branch compared to the branch it tracks, and tools that add branch information to your prompt typically can be configured to display that as well. While multiple branches can use a particular commit as its head, only one (the checked-out branch) is updated on the next commit; that's precisely what it means to check out a branch: the next commit uses the branch's head as its parent and updates the branch pointer.

Comment: No reference is pointing to your working copy. What you're asking for is to list references pointing to your HEAD reference, which itself is pointing to a tip of your current (checked out) branch (i.e. your latest commit).

Comment: @DawidFerenczy That's correct; working copy and HEAD are totally different things. I think the OP meant branches' tips pointing to the same commit. The thing is, just because branches point to the *same tip*, doesn't mean they have the same *history*.

Comment: @Rafael I agree. We have described the same thing. Branches themselves are also just references. So he needs to list all branches pointing to a commit the `HEAD` reference points to (the latest commit of the currently checked out branch). And that's what he gets using the command in jthill's answer.

Comment: @Rafael what do you mean by history for branches, if not the tip commit's ancestry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git log -1 --pretty=%D
```

will get you the text

Comment: Just a note: no branch can reference your working copy. This command shows what references are pointing to your HEAD reference, which itself is pointing to a tip of your current branch (i.e. your latest commit).

Comment: All answers (3 so far) uses completely different git concepts (well, 2 uses branches, but one uses branches contents and other repo graph) to achieve the same thing! i am "accepting" the one older and with most votes, but all are correct

Answer (score 2):

```
git branch --all --points-at HEAD
```

is the thing you are looking for according to the manual:

```
   -a, --all
       List both remote-tracking branches and local branches.

  --points-at <object>
       Only list branches of the given object.
```

Variants exists if you want to also see other refs (e.g. tags) or use the result in scripts - in which case you don't want to mess around with `sed` just to remove unnecessary stuff:

```
> git for-each-ref --points-at HEAD --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads refs/remotes
master
otherbranch
origin/master
origin/HEAD
```

Comment: this way has more descriptive arguments (and only gives branches, as opposed to tags from the `git log` answer) but requires git 2+. on git 1.x you only have `git branch -a` (not even --all), and --points-at doesn't exist yet.

Comment: `git branch -a --contains` from another answer will work on git 1.x

Comment: @Gabriel But `--contains` also returns branches which are descendants of `HEAD` not just those which point to `HEAD`.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch --all --contains HEAD
```